# How to restore MSDB database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, restore

I lost MSDB database in SQL 2005. How do I restore that?

Comment: Hopefully you have backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out

http://rip747.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/rebulding-msdb-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rebuild:
http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/06/619304.aspx

If you want to restore from backup:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190749.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction from http://rip747.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/rebulding-msdb-in-sql-server-2005/ and it worked.
Thank s Tapori.